# Apache AVRO with Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, avro

Does anyone know hot to use Apache AVRO RPC with Spring boot? Every single AVRO implementation I have seen is hosted on a netty server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be trying to achieve the same thing I'm trying to achieve -- speeding up json serialization with spring boot and spring web.  Or maybe you just want to use avro?  And my comment is a little late, since it's months after you posted.  I have run across this information about using an avro message converter, so thought I would share it with you to see if it helps:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.RELEASE/reference/html/contenttypemanagement.html#_schema_based_message_converters

Or did you already find it?  If so, can you share whatever solution that you came up with?  Our rest json serialization takes much longer than the whole rest of the operation and I would like to speed it up as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for! I needed it for a proof of concept that I hadn't yet found time to work on. Maybe now that I have a new lead, I will! Thanks a lot!

Comment: And regarding your question, I was looking into avro for a proof of concept for both speeding up serialization and decreasing the data trasnfered using avro serialization.

Comment: For speeding up serialization and deserialization, have you checked into Kryo?  I was experimenting with it, and it looks pretty promising.